# Not able to wget to ftp server

Tags: linux, proxy, ftp, terminal, wget

I am trying to wget a ftp server from a remote machine. The command is not getting past `'Logging in as anonymous'`. This is what i am getting.

```
 wget ftp://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/chromosomes/chr1.fa.gz
--2013-09-29 22:07:53--  ftp://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/chromosomes/chr1.fa.gz
           => ‘chr1.fa.gz’
Resolving proxy.x.y.z... *.*.*.*
Connecting to proxy.x.y.z|*.*.*.*|:3128... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ...
```

When i try accessing the site by firefox from the remote machine, it works fine. I have set my ftp proxy like this

```
export ftp_proxy="ftp://a.user:password@proxy:3128
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try set proxy env that way? (http:// instead of ftp://)

```
$ export ftp_proxy=http://a.user:password@proxy.domain:3128
```

also you can do it other way, please create a file ~/.wgetrc containing below settings:

```
http_proxy = http://a.user:password@proxy.domain:3128 
ftp_proxy = http://a.user:password@proxy.domain:3128 
proxy_user = username
proxy_password = password 
use_proxy = on
```

Answer (score 1):

That link worked for me successfully.

$: wget ftp://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/chromosomes/chr1.fa.gz--2013-09-30

```
23:34:58--  ftp://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/chromosomes/chr1.fa.gz
           => `chr1.fa.gz.1'
Resolving hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu (hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu)... 128.114.119.163
Connecting to hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu (hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu)|128.114.119.163|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /goldenPath/hg19/chromosomes ... done.
==> SIZE chr1.fa.gz ... 73773666
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR chr1.fa.gz ... done.
Length: 73773666 (70M) (unauthoritative)

 3% [=>                                                             ] 2,810,568    101K/s  eta 10m 57s
```

In my `/etc/wgetrc`

```
passive_ftp = on
```

`$: wget --version`

```
GNU Wget 1.13.4 built on linux-gnu.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls +ntlm +opie +ssl/openssl 

Wgetrc: 
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: /usr/share/locale 
Compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc" 
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../../src -I../lib 
    -I../../lib -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Iyes/include -g -O2 
    -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat 
    -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -DNO_SSLv2 
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall 
Link: gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat 
    -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -DNO_SSLv2 
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions 
    -Wl,-z,relro -Lyes/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lz -lidn -lrt 
    ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a
```

OS: `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS 64 bit`

I'm on my home LAN connected on a DHCP router, connected to the WAN cable modem with a dynamic IP address to a residential ISP.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue I've set the following env:

```
#PROXY_URL=http://proxy_usr:proxy_pwd@localhost:3128
PROXY_URL=http://localhost:3128
export HTTP_PROXY=$PROXY_URL
export http_proxy=$PROXY_URL
export HTTPS_PROXY=$PROXY_URL
export https_proxy=$PROXY_URL
export FTP_PROXY=$PROXY_URL
export ftp_proxy=$PROXY_URL
export no_proxy='localhost,127.0.0.1,.yourdomain.com'
alias curl='curl -x $PROXY_URL'
git config --global http.proxy $PROXY_URL
git config --global https.proxy $PROXY_URL
```